# prepend newline to all phrases that match a pattern

Tags: sed

Suppose my text file looks like this `foobar foo bar foobar barfoo`.
I need to add a new line to the front of `bar` (notice the space before AND after 'bar')

In other words, after running the `sed` command, I expect to see this

```
foobar foo
bar foobar barfoo
```

I've tried the following, but none of them worked!
sed  -r 's/bar/\nbar/;'
sed  -r 's/( bar )/\nbar/;'

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$ sed -r 's/ (bar )/\n\1/' file
foobar foo
bar foobar barfoo
```

You can add the `g` flag for global substitution if you have more than one bar on one line.